Patching Event/OnlineMeeting Attendees does not remove all attendees
I used C# Graph SDK(Microsoft.Graph 5.61.0) to test Patch an Event with Application Permission
/*Calendars.ReadWrite | Application | Read and write calendars in all mailboxes | Yes*/
var client = GetAppGraphServiceClient(config);
if (client == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Init Graph Client Error...");
    return;
}

string userId = "user-id";
string eventId = "event-id";
var theEvent = await client.Users[userId].Events[eventId].GetAsync();

var updatedAttendees = new List<Attendee>();
theEvent.Attendees.ForEach(attendee =>
{
    if (attendee.EmailAddress.Address != "OneExisted@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com")
    {
        //Attendee attendee1 = new Attendee();
        //EmailAddress emailAddress1 = new EmailAddress();
        //emailAddress1.Address = attendee.EmailAddress.Address;
        //attendee1.EmailAddress = emailAddress1;
        //updatedAttendees.Add(attendee1);

        updatedAttendees.Add(attendee);
    }
});

var updatedEvent = new Event
{
    Attendees = updatedAttendees
};

var newEvent = await client.Users[userId].Events[eventId].PatchAsync(updatedEvent);

//@event.Attendees = updatedAttendees;
//var updated = await client.Users[userId].Events[eventId].PatchAsync(@event);

but the Attendees of newEvent have no any change compared with theEvent whether it is a one-time removal or one-by-one removal.
I try to change Subject and it effects
var updatedEvent2 = new Event
{
    Subject = "Updated Subject",
};

var newEvent2 = await client.Users[userId].Events[eventId].PatchAsync(updatedEvent2);
//it had is changed

I also tested patching OnlineMeeting with an application permission and application access policy. I added two attendees as participants, then tried to remove the two attendees one at a time. However, the attendees list didn't change. If I just try to remove first attendee, it succeeded, afterwards there was just one attendee in the meeting. If I then tried to remove last attendee, the attendees list didn't change at all.
var theMeeting = await client.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].GetAsync();

var updatedMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    Participants = new MeetingParticipants
    {
        Attendees = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>(),
    }
};

var newMeeting = await client.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings[onlineMeetingId].PatchAsync(updatedMeeting);

How can I use PATCH Attendees to correctly remove attendees?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Rust? JavaScript?C#? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

The same issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2108723/how-to-update-attendees-for-onlinemeeting-in-graph. Please follow the above-mentioned thread for further updates.
